# Customize IE toolbar

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, address-bar

I wanted to know if there is a way to customize toolbars in IE.
I just want to change the position [dock to left right or bottom] of menubar, addressbar at the bottom instead of default top location. Just that I feel that way it would be more comfortable for me.

Answer (score 1):

In IE9, some additional constraints were placed on the toolbars, so that as far as I know there is very little that can be moved.

The maximum that you can do is right-click on the toolbars area or on the Gear button (located upper right hand corner) and ensure that "Lock the toolbars" is unchecked. You may then move toolbars by dragging the little dotted handle on their left.

But as I said, the choices are limited : All one can do is reorder the toolbars, not move them elsewhere than at the top.